# How can I change a label content to something else using a method

Tags: wpf, methods, label

This is my method I created to edit the content of the label inside  TourCollection.cs:

```
 public void Start()    
    {       
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();      
        mw.Label1.Content= "Hello";          
    }
```

This is the button event i created to run the method OnClick in MainWindow.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)       
    {        
        TourCollection t = new TourCollection();       
        t.Start();         
    }
```

This is the button code inside MainWindow.xaml:

```
   <Button Content="Find Out More" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="258" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.326,-0.981" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

This is my label I created in MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Label x:Name="Label1" Content="Label" Canvas.Left="254" Canvas.Top="33"/>
```

Comment: Your question is very vague and unclear! Please try to refine your way of asking

Comment: I would like to change my current Label1 from "Label" to "Hello" using a method called Start() from my TourCollection class

Comment: The Start() Method will change Label1.content but it is not working on my side

Comment: It doesn't work because it refers to a new `MainWindow` object and not your current one. We know nothing about the current layout of the program, i.e what window you call it from for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you want to do 
Make the label Modifies **public** in the design properties.

In your Button_Click do this

```
t.Start(this);
```

And your Start function will now become

```
 public void Start(MainWindow instance) 
{ 
 instance.Label1.Content= "Hello"; 
}
```

Your problem was you were creating a new Main window and changing the text there. What you wanted was to change the text in Label1 of the currently open window.

Comment: Thank You so much i totally understand from you explanation sorry for the phrasing the question properly just now but thank you ! Merry Christmas